# How to improve coding skills?

Tags: logic, programming-languages

I can't say I'm weak in programming but I can't come up with the logic faster. I can analyse others code and get to know the logic. But I can't do it on my own. How can I improve my programming skills?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite a broad question but from my own, 30yr experience I can tell you there is no way around starting to

- analyze existing code,
- modify some things (play with it until it feels like it's your own code)
- see what the changes do
- develop your own ideas on how to do things faster/better/more beautiful
- implement your ideas
- see if it works
- go on to more complex tasks
- read books (very important, because many things can't just be discovered by trial'n'error)
- be very passionate and determined about what you want to become reality
- if you want to learn faster, then write more code
- One very important item. You should have fun with what you do is always the best guarantee for success

If you fail at these items then I'm afraid you will never succeed with programming. But then maybe it's like any other field of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I experience the same difficulties during my learning journey, too. When I complete challenge tasks I create more complex tasks for myself to see what I can do. It takes me to the next levels of solving problems. 
Practice, Practice, Practice!